# hibernate query on dates greater than

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have been trying to find a way to query on all dates in my table where the modded date is older than 7 days.

Here is something I had in the works but it will not work:

```
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Ownership> findOwnersByDate() {
    log.debug("finding a filtered list of Ownerships");
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Ownership.class)
        .add( Restrictions.gt("modDate", new Integer(7) ) ); 
        List results = crit.list();
        log.debug("get filtered ownerships successful, 
                    result size: " +  results.size());
        return results;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.debug("query failed", re);
        log.error("get filtered ownerships failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try putting a Date/Calendar object in the `gt()` instead of an Integer, whichever type your `modDate` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing `new Integer(7)` to `Restrictions.gt()`, try passing a Date object corresponding to the current date minus 7 days. You can use the Calendar class for that, e.g.:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
...
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Ownership.class)
    .add( Restrictions.gt("modDate", cal.getTime() ) );
```